# make sure to include the file in Jest's transformIgnorePatterns as wel

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to make jest/enzyme tests in react

I have this test:

```
import React from 'react';

import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

import WorkOutForm from './workOutForm';

describe('WorkOutForm', () => {
      it('should start a new workoutForm with empty state', () => {
        const component = mount(<WorkOutForm/>)

        expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
   })
```

but when i do a `npm run test` i receive:

> src/workout/workOut.test.js   ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> babel-jest: Babel ignores src/workout/workOutForm.jsx - make sure to include the file in Jest's transformIgnorePatterns as well.
> ```

I try to add this file in the package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "src/workout/workOutForm.jsx"
    ]
  }
```

but i'm receiving the same error.
where i have to put this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where i have to put this?

You should **not** ignore jsx source files. What you need to do is convert your jsx to js using babel.

You need to use [babel-preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react). This will automatically add [`@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) for the transformation.

Then put this in your `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already this error and i fixed changing the code from:

```
"ignore": [
   "./test",
   "./src/assets",
   "./src/stories",
   "./src/.storybook"
]
```

To this:

```
"ignore": [
   "./src/assets",
   "./src/stories",
   "./src/.storybook"
]
```

I remove my test folder from the .babelrc ignore prop and its works for me!